# Put in a cell the sum of specific cells if other cells contains a specific text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am a novice in Excel. I want to have a formula for the following condition (shown in line 20 in the image):

AF is the sum of the columns in red (D, H and L) only if the associated column on their right (E, I and M) contains the letter 'X'. In the image below the sum is 700 because only I and M contains X. If E would contains 'X' the sum would it be 1050.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=SUM(IF(E20="x",D20,0),IF(I20="x",H20,0),IF(M20="x",L20,0))
```

Copy this code to cell AF20, then extend it.

Answer (score 1):

If you would consider using 1 instead of X, then it becomes much simpler :

```
=D20*E20+H20*I20+L20*M20
```

So, E20 is 0 then I20 is 1 and M20 is 1.

Edit based on Richard's excellent suggestion which means you keep the X's as original:

```
=D20*ISTEXT(E20)+H20*ISTEXT(I20)+L20*ISTEXT(M20)
```

WARNING, this will assume ANY text X, Z, G, will be true so will get counted...

Comment: This would be my approach with `NOT(ISBLANK())` or `ISTEXT()` to translate the cell to 0 or 1

Answer (score 1):

Use SUMIF:

```
=SUMIF(E20:M20,"x",D20:L20)
```

Comment: Just elegant as usual... +1 (and why did I not see that grrr)